# Can't retrieve emails from shared group mailbox using Exchange Web Services Managed API

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I'm trying to use Exchange Web Services Managed API to connect to a group mailbox and return the emails from it's inbox. I was able to do so with my personal email account but I have been unsuccessful with the group mailbox. I have access to the Group mailbox in Outlook.  I included the code I used to select the email from the group mailbox.  I was  not sure what the URI should look like so I tried two different formats.
https://server3.mycompany.com which returned the following error.

> The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

and https://server3.mycompany.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx which never returned and timed out.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
\\service.Url = new Uri("https://server3.mycompany.com");
service.Url = new Uri(@"https://server3.mycompany.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
Mailbox gpmailbox = new Mailbox("CouponInterfacePool@mycompany.com");
FolderId gpInbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, gpmailbox);
ItemView view = new ItemView(10);
FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.FindItems(gpInbox, view);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To figure out your company's URI

- ON your client machine, hold down CTRL and right click on the small Outlook icon on Windows Taskbar
- select Test E-mail AutoConfiguration...
- enter Email Address and Password
- Press Test button

In the Results tab you'll find the URI on Availability Service URL.

Comment: I was using the correct URL.  The issue was caused by trying to assign the service.Url. Simply put the mailbox URL in the Mmailbox method and don't try to set the URL.

Comment: The following code works `ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1); service.UseDefaultCredentials = true; Mailbox gpmailbox = new Mailbox ("CouponInterfacePool@mycompany.com"); FolderId gpInbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, gpmailbox); ItemView view = new ItemView(10); FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.FindItems(gpInbox, view);`